# How would I display an image in the background while the loading bar progresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, loading

So i made a loading bar and managed to get it working successfully. However, I want to display an image in the background while the progress bar is progressing and my actions have gone to dust whenever I try.

I tried to add a new line which would constantly "blit" the image.
screen.blit(loadingimg) but it ended up giving this error:

```
DS.blit(loadingimg)
TypeError: function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)
```

```
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",25)
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def loading(progress):
    if progress < 100:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(int(progress)) + "%", True, green)
    else:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(100) + "%", True, green)

    DS.blit(text, [453, 273])

def message_to_screen(msh, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = HW, HH + y_displace
    DS.blit(textSurf, textRect)

while (progress/2) < 100:
    event_handler()
    DS.fill(WHITE)
    DS.blit(loadingimg)
    time_count = (random.randint(1,1))
    increase = random.randint(1,20)
    progress += increase
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [423, 223, 204, 49])
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, BLACK, [424, 224, 202, 47])
    if (progress/2) > 100:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [425, 225, 200, 45])
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [425, 225, progress, 45])
    loading(progress/2)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(time_count)
```

What's supposed to happen is that a loading bar appears and while the progress bar is loading, there's an image in the background. After the progress bar reaches 100%, it will move on to the next thing but in this case, I just want both of them to disappear after reaching 100%

My actual output is just this error:

```
DS.blit(loadingimg)
TypeError: function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)
```

Comment: see documentation for [blit()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) - it needs not only image but also position - `blit(image, (x,y))` - `DS.blit(loadingimg, (0, 0)) `

Comment: Silly mistake on my behalf, thank you man

Answer (score 1):

See documentation for [blit()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). It needs also position - `blit(image, (x,y))` or `blit(image, rect)`

```
DS.blit(loadingimg, (0, 0))
```

`blit()` is used to display not only background but also player's image, enemies' images - and they can be displayed in any place on screen.